# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel c# Webrequest

Tags: c#, rest, wcf, ssl, service

I am trying to call a service by using below set of code in c#.
i'am using the .NET Framework 4.6.2. and whenever i reach the code (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse(), it is throwing an exception "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel". I tried many solutions said in stack overflow. but none of them were not helpful for me. i am struggling on this from last one week then finally posting here. please any help will be appreciated.
I even added the certificated in local stores but still no use. below is my code.

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Uri myUri = new Uri("https://CallingUrl");
WebRequest myWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(myUri);
HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)myWebRequest;
string svcCredentials = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("User:Pwd"));
myHttpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + svcCredentials);
myHttpWebRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
myHttpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
myHttpWebRequest.Method = "POST"
HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Can you get this working in postman? Have you got the documentation from the author for the service? Also why are you using webrequest and not HttpClient, is there a specific use case?

Comment: I have checked this in postman tool there i'm getting the proper response. and i also tried with HttpClient then also i'm facing the same issue @MichaelRandall

Comment: Have you tried changing the ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol

Comment: Yes i tried SS3,Tls,Tls11,Tls12 but still no use @MichaelRandall

Comment: This may be a problem with the HttpWebRequest request, you can try to add a service reference to call the service instead of directly constructing an http request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code is perfectly fine. but this issue was caused by other reason.

After digging into a lot finally go the solution, and thought it will help others who are facing same issue so posting this answer.

**Cause :**

By default limit in **Schannel** implementation is 32768 bytes. Once it reached the maximum limit it will return above error at the time of handshake between Service.

**Resolution :**

1. Increase the MessageLimitClient from Default 0x8000 to max 0xf000 with the registry key
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\Schannel\**Messaging**
2. Create the **Messaging** Key if it is not present
3. Then Create New DWORD name it as '**MessageLimitClient**' and set the Valuedata as '**f000**' (hexadecimal).
4. After changing this value, restart server to take effect of new value.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this solution did not help in my case (at least not without restart). But there is a problem in the description. 1st: I did not have the key `Messaging` in registry. 2nd: In text description is written **Max**LimitClient but on the image is **Message**LimitClient.

Comment: edited. if you do not have Messaging, then you need to create it. i mentioned it

Comment: I added the key (both, the old and the new) and unfortunately it did not help me to fix the error. Now I'm working on a solution using Python as HTTP request reader.

Comment: there are many reasons which causes the same issue. in your case the cause is some thing else may be @Julo